# Why database palette is not supported in Eclipse?

Tags: palette

My Eclipse: **Kepler**

- When using Eclipse I am not able to use the Palette Database?
- Why i don't see database palette in the Eclipse?
- But it is present in Netbeans.

Comment: NetBeans is neither affiliated with Eclipse, nor shares codebase. They're basically different products.

Comment: If you need such a thing, then why don't you use NetBeans?

Comment: Insomuch Eclipse is Open source and it is with better plugins and more. Now the Eclipse is it?